# SwiftUI - How to display countdown timer

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to display a countdown timer, which will take the current hour, minute, second, then count down to 00:00:00. Currently I have the current date displayed, But it's adding up.

My expectation: It will count down and when it gets back to 00:00:00 it will stop.

Below is all my code

```
struct TimerView: View {
    @State var timeRemaining = 24*60*60
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 12) {
            timerStringView(timer: "\(hourString(timer: timeRemaining))")
            timerStringView(timer: "\(minutesString(timer: timeRemaining))")
            timerStringView(timer: "\(secondsString(timer: timeRemaining))")
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 34)
        .background(Color.gray)
        .onReceive(timer) { _ in
            if timeRemaining > 0 {
                timeRemaining -= 1
            } else {
                timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func timerStringView(timer: String) -> some View {
        Text(timer)
            .font(.system(size: 18, weight: .bold))
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .background(Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(6)
    }
    
    func hourString(timer: Int) -> String {
        let date = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let hours = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
        return String(format: "%02i", hours)
    }
    
    func minutesString(timer: Int) -> String {
        let date = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
        return String(format: "%02i", minutes)
    }
    
    func secondsString(timer: Int) -> String {
        let date = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let second = calendar.component(.second, from: date)
        return String(format: "%02i", second)
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is "the current hour, minute, second" in this context? Is that the value in `timeRemaining` or is it based on the current time of day?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Is the current hour, minute, and second on your computer. I have shown it on the code above

Comment: So if it's five minutes after midnight then you want to count down from 5 minutes to zero and if it is five minutes before midnight then you want to countdown from 23 hours and 55 minutes down to zero? And what do you mean you have shown it in the code, in your `hourString` function and the others you are only using the current date without doing any countdown at all?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson That's right, i just want to use the current hour, minute, second, and then count it down to 00:00:00

Comment: But that doesn't make sense if you are always getting a new Date instance each time the timer fires and as I said you are not doing any countdown at all in your code. Assign the current time to a property once when you start the timer and then decrease it with one second every time the timer fires and update the UI with the new value. This should at least get you closer to what you want to achieve.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I'm just a beginner, Can you edit it on my code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255531/discussion-between-lucky-and-joakim-danielson).

Comment: Create a new property `@State var startDate = Date()` and update it when the timer fires, `startDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: -1, to: startDate)!`. Then use this `startDate` property in your functions instead of the local variable you are now using. Hopefully this will be more of what you wanted to achieve.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I would be very grateful if you could edit my code directly

Comment: I think it's important to not that *"A timer is not a real-time mechanism"* (from the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer)) so using subtracting the way you are is going to introduce a level of inaccuracy - you should be calculating the amount of time which has passed since the timer was started

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using on appear get the hours minutes and seconds all added up into seconds to set the @State. Note: taking the hours and multiplying by 3600 was bugging out, so I used an extra variable to fix it on my machine.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var timeRemaining:Int = 0
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 12) {
            timerStringView(timer: "\(hourString(timer: timeRemaining))")
            timerStringView(timer: "\(minutesString(timer: timeRemaining))")
            timerStringView(timer: "\(secondsString(timer: timeRemaining))")
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 34)
        .background(Color.gray)
        .onReceive(timer) { _ in
            if timeRemaining > 0 {
                timeRemaining -= 1
            } else {
                timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
            }
        }
        // Get the time
        .onAppear() {
            setTimer()
        }
    }
    
    func timerStringView(timer: String) -> some View {
        Text(timer)
            .font(.system(size: 18, weight: .bold))
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .background(Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(6)
    }
    func hourString(timer: Int) -> String {
        let date = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let hours = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
        return String(format: "%02i", hours)
    }
    
    func minutesString(timer: Int) -> String {
        let date = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
        return String(format: "%02i", minutes)
    }
    
    func secondsString(timer: Int) -> String {
        let date = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let second = calendar.component(.second, from: date)
        return String(format: "%02i", second)
    }
    func setTimer() {
        let date = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let hours = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
        let hourSeconds = hours * 3600
        let minuteSeconds = calendar.component(.minute, from: date) * 60
        let seconds = calendar.component(.second, from: date)
        timeRemaining = hourSeconds
        timeRemaining += minuteSeconds
        timeRemaining += seconds
    }
}
```

Comment: This countdown timer can show incorrect time if you minimize window.

Answer (score 2):

It's important to note that the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer) state that

> A timer is **not a real-time mechanism**. If a timer’s firing time occurs during a long run loop callout or while the run loop is in a mode that isn't monitoring the timer, the timer doesn't fire until the next time the run loop checks the timer. Therefore, the actual **time at which a timer fires can be significantly later**

As such you should not be relying on simply incrementing an arbitrary value on each firing of the `Timer`.  Time is also not stable, there aren't always 24 hours in day for example.

This could lead to a drift in your output even over a short period of time.

Instead, you should be calculating the amount of actual time which has passed.

For example...

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var duration = "---"
    private let timeStarted = Date()
    private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    static var duratioinFormatter: DateComponentsFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
        formatter.unitsStyle = .abbreviated
        formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .dropLeading
        return formatter
    }()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack(spacing: 12) {
                Spacer()
                Text(duration)
                    .font(.system(size: 18, weight: .bold))
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
                    .background(Color.gray)
                    .cornerRadius(6)
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 34)
        .onReceive(timer) { _ in
            let delta = Date().timeIntervalSince(timeStarted)
            duration = ContentView.duratioinFormatter.string(from: delta) ?? "---"
        }
    }
}
```

This will count up from the `timeStarted`.  You also get localisation for free.

To count down, you flip the concept around.  That is, you create a `Date` value in the future and then get the `timeIntervalSince` between it and now, for example...

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var duration = "---"
    private let desiredDuration = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 5, to: Date())!
    private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    static var duratioinFormatter: DateComponentsFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
        formatter.unitsStyle = .abbreviated
        formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .dropLeading
        return formatter
    }()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack(spacing: 12) {
                Spacer()
                Text(duration)
                    .font(.system(size: 18, weight: .bold))
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
                    .background(Color.gray)
                    .cornerRadius(6)
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 34)
        .onReceive(timer) { _ in
            var delta = desiredDuration.timeIntervalSince(Date())
            if delta <= 0 {
                delta = 0
                timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
            }
            duration = ContentView.duratioinFormatter.string(from: delta) ?? "---"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Andrew_STOP_RU_WAR_IN_UA How - it's based on actual time - if it jumps, then it's demonstrating the documented behaviour of the `Timer` and underlying run-loop (and in my quick test, it worked just fine)

Comment: @Andrew_STOP_RU_WAR_IN_UA which is why my solution is based on Date and time difference, not counter - also, it will depend on the runloop the timer is running in, I don’t know about SwiftUI, but in UIKit you can disconnect it from the main loop - also, I was running on the Mac, so iOS life cycle might be different

Comment: upvoted, you're right. Best solution here

Answer (score 0):

33333's answer works, but it counts *up*. Here's a modified version of his code that counts *down*. You should use `newDate.timeIntervalSince(oldDate)` to figure out the number of seconds.

My particular application only needs an interval in minutes and seconds, so I coded it that way, but it shouldn't be too difficult to do the necessary math to calculate any other units desired.

```
import SwiftUI


struct CountdownView: View {
    @State var timeRemaining: Int

    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            timerStringView(timer: "\(minutesString(timer: timeRemaining))")
            Text(":")
                .font(.system(size: 36, weight: .bold))
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .background(Color.white)
            timerStringView(timer: "\(secondsString(timer: timeRemaining))")
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 34)
        .onReceive(timer) { _ in
            if timeRemaining > 0 {
                timeRemaining -= 1
            } else {
                timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
            }
        }
        // Get the time
        .onAppear() {
            setTimer()
        }
    }

    func timerStringView(timer: String) -> some View {
        Text(timer)
            .font(.system(size: 36, weight: .bold))
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .background(Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(6)
    }

    func minutesString(timer: Int) -> String {
        let minutes = timer / 60
        return String(format: "%02i", minutes)
    }

    func secondsString(timer: Int) -> String {
        let seconds = timer % 60
        return String(format: "%02i", seconds)
    }

    func setTimer() {
        timeRemaining = 300
    }
}

struct CountdownView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CountdownView(timeRemaining: 300)
    }
}
```

Comment: This countdown timer can show incorrect time if you minimize window. Also.

Comment: Please let me know about fixes, or post them as a new (better) answer! I think this should probably work for iOS, but I haven't tested (say) backgrounding the app.

Comment: Check the answer of ***MadProgrammer***, it's better because of use ```timeStarted``` variable. But the best way is to implement solution based on ```CFTimeInterval``` like the following stopwatch: https://github.com/Kyst2/Kala/blob/master/Kala/Kala/Backend/Stopwatch.swift . It is the best because of highest possible accuracy.

Comment: This looks good. I'll try it out in my app and see if it delivers what I need.