# How to make a countdown timer using Time Remaining

Tags: swift, swiftui, countdown, countdowntimer

I want to implement a countdown timer, based on the current time and end time.

For example:

- Current time: 20:30:30
- End time always is : 23:59:59

  **-> I will implement a countdown timer as: 03:29:29**

Comment: You can use `Duration` and its built-in ability to format itself into a whole bunch of different styles https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/duration/timeformatstyle

Comment: @Alexander Can you give me an example based on my code?

Comment: A continuation/duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77256254/how-can-i-calculate-the-remaining-time-for-the-countdown-timer) and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77237979/swiftui-how-to-display-countdown-timer) I assume.

Comment: @LangThang Oh I didn't realize that `23`, `59` and `59` were the target time. I thought they were constants used just for formatting. Yeah this is missing some key pieces. Your explanation of the code talks about "Current time" and "end time", yet the notion of "end time" doesn't exist in your code. That's a sign of something that's missing.

Comment: ... Which is exactly what `endDateComponents` is doing in Vadian's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way is to do the date math with `DateComponents`, there is an API `dateComponents(_:from:to:)` where `from` and `to` can be `DateComponents`

```
struct TimerView: View {
    @State private var differenceComponents = DateComponents()

    private let endDateComponents = DateComponents(hour: 23, minute: 59, second: 59)
    private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    private let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 12) {
            timerStringView(value: differenceComponents.hour ?? 0)
            timerStringView(value: differenceComponents.minute ?? 0 )
            timerStringView(value: differenceComponents.second ?? 0)
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 34)
        .background(Color.gray)
        .onReceive(timer) { _ in
            updateComponents()
        }
        .onAppear(perform: updateComponents)
    }
    
    func updateComponents() {
        let nowComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: .now)
        differenceComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: nowComponents, to: endDateComponents)
    }
    
    func timerStringView(value: Int) -> some View {
        Text(String(format: "%02d", value))
            .font(.system(size: 18, weight: .bold))
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .background(Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(6)
    }
}
```

Comment: The `differenceComponents`'s initial value is all zeros, which will show briefly for the first second. You'll probably want to set it to the time diff. Is there a better way to do that than `onAppear`?

Comment: @vadian I want the countdown timer to stop if nowComponents is greater than or equal to endDateComponents. Can you help me?

Comment: @LangThang Respectfully, your question(s) are growing starting to have scope creep. You would be best served by learning the basics and being able to tackle these things by yourself. You already seem to have a pretty good ability to decompose a complex problem into smaller individually-answerable questions, and that's a good place to start. I would suggest getting some structured resource (book, course, etc., but not one-off blogs or articles) that teach SwiftUI programming from start to finish.

Comment: @Alexander You are right about the initial value, thanks, answer edited.